# Does Apple's stock Reminders app geofencing work with iBeacons?

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation, ibeacon

I'd like to know whether geofenced reminders in Apple's stock Reminders app can use iBeacons to trigger.

My use case is that I'd like to place an iBeacon in my home, and trigger reminders when it is detected by iOS/CoreLocation. The default GPS-based location finding can be less than prompt, since GPS reception near my home can be hit-or-miss. I've been unable to find specific confirmation that this is supported in the stock app. I may have to go to something like [Proximitask](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/proximitask-beacon-based-reminders/id872968023?mt=8) if the stock app doesn't support this use case.

Comment: Proximitask definitely has worked reasonably well in the past for me, but with the latest iOS update, I can no longer delete Proximitask reminders.  They look like they delete, but the next time I come in range of the iBeacon, they pop back up.  So I look forward to seeing what you find because the value of my notifications is going down rapidly.